# Projecting content using selectors coming in through ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, ng-template, ng-content

I have a `toolbar` component that projects content into multiple slots using selectors:

```
<ng-content select="[left]"></ng-content>
<ng-content></ng-content>
<ng-content select="[right]"></ng-content>
```

When used directly in a parent it the content is projected correctly:

```
<section>
  <p>Content is projected correctly</p>
  <toolbar>   
    <button>Center</button>
    <button right>Right</button>
    <button left>Left</button>
</toolbar>
</section>
```

[Content displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbll7.png)

When using an `ng-template` and `ngTemplateOutlet` to pass the content to the toolbar it doesn't work. The content is projected, but all content ends up in the `<ng-content></ng-content>` catch-all.

```
<ng-template #toolbarContent>
  <button>Center</button>
  <button right>Right</button>
  <button left>Left</button>
</ng-template>

<section>
  <p>Content is projected incorrectly</p>
  <toolbar><ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="toolbarContent"></ng-container></toolbar>
</section>
```

[Content displayed incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IczDQ.png)

How can I make the content in the template provided through `ngTemplateOutlet` project to the right slot?

Stackblitz code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grid-toolbar?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Both your link to images point to the same one, the incorrect case

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed.